# OpenCV in c++ linked with binding.gyp, does not read Videofile with VideoCapture?

Tags: c++, opencv, electron

In electron, I want to add a .cpp target, that uses OpenCv and it's VideoCapture. 
My binding.gyp looks like:

```
    {
  "targets": [
    {
       "target_name": "wrapper",
       "sources": ["src/wrapper.cpp"],
        "libraries": [
           "/home/hagen/Desktop/opencv-3.3.1/build/lib/libopencv_*.so"
           ],
        'cflags_cc!': ['-fno-rtti', '-fno-exceptions'],
        'cflags_cc+': ['-frtti', '-fexceptions']
        }
  ]
}
```

I installed opencv like this: https://linuxhint.com/how-to-install-opencv-on-ubuntu/

The target, wrapper.cpp, looks roughly like:

```
 #include <node.h>
    #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/cvconfig.h>
    using namespace cv;


    void init(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args){
      v8::Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
      v8::String::Utf8Value param1(args[0]->ToString());

      std::string video_path= "/home/hagen/Desktop/VisoProj-TBP/videos/street.mp4";

        #if defined(HAVE_FFMPEG)
          std::cout<<"ffmpeg yes\n";
        #else
          std::cout<<"no\n";
        #endif

        cv::VideoCapture vid=cv::VideoCapture(video_path, cv::CAP_FFMPEG);
        if(!vid.isOpened())
        {
            std::cout << "!!! Failed to open file: " <<video_path << std::endl;
        }
}

    void Initialize(v8::Local<v8::Object> exports) {
      NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "init", init);
    }

    NODE_MODULE(wrapper, Initialize)
```

It tells me, that "HAVE_FFMPEG" ist true, but it does not open the .mp4 file. Other OpenCV functions, like imread() and imwrite do work fine. In a standalone .cpp application, I can use OpenCV with ffmpeg and I can read that specific .mp4 file with the same absolute path.

Any Ideas, how to get the VideoCapture working with the .mp4 file? Maybe my binding is wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: For now, a workaround: Insted of VideoCapture(video_path, cv::CAP_FFMPEG); I use VideoCapture(video_path, cv::CAP_IMAGES); So I don't use the .mp4 file, but a folder full of images like "./street/street%04d.jpg"